# DXA 1.5 Java website was working - now failing with "Cannot determine entity type for semantic schema names"

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java

We had the DXA 1.5 staging website working in Tomcat on Linux. Then suddenly it stopped and Tomcat just errors (see below) whenever we request any page. We have restarted everything. The site also fails when run on our Windows server with the same broker databases. We are running SDL Web 8.1.

I can only think we have changed some content dependency but we were only editing and publishing pages.

It looks like something to do with the Default Mediaitem Schema.

Can anyone point us in the right direction?

> 16:25:44.141 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR c.s.w.c.i.m.ViewModelRegistryImpl - Cannot determine entity type for semantic schema names: '[http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema]'. Please make sure that an entry is registered for this view name in the ViewModelRegistry.
>   16:25:44.141 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing request for: /
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createInstance(SemanticMapperImpl.java:54) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createEntity(SemanticMapperImpl.java:97) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.EntityBuilderImpl.createEntity(EntityBuilderImpl.java:298) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.EntityBuilderImpl.createEntity(EntityBuilderImpl.java:278) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipeline.java:104) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.converters.ComponentLinkFieldConverter.createComponentLink(ComponentLinkFieldConverter.java:122) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.converters.ComponentLinkFieldConverter.getFieldValues(ComponentLinkFieldConverter.java:60) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.converters.AbstractFieldConverter.getFieldValue(AbstractFieldConverter.java:23) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.SemanticFieldDataProviderImpl.getFieldData(SemanticFieldDataProviderImpl.java:151) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl$1.doWith(SemanticMapperImpl.java:123) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:570) ~[spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:547) ~[spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have published a binary (i.e. used it somewhere in a Component which is on a published Page) based on the Default Multimedia Schema.

The Default Multimedia Schema is not mapped in DXA, i.e. there is no Entity class for it, and this is what the error is trying to tell you.

If you have a specific reason for using the Default Multimedia Schema, then you should add an Entity model for it in your DXA web application. Or probabaly what you wanted to do was just add an image, or a download file, in that case, you should delete the Multimedia Component which you created using the Default Multimedia Schema and recreate it using either the Image or Download Schema.

ps. the reason why there still is a Default Multimedia Schema, is because that is a default of Tridion, and we didn't remove any of these defaults.

Comment: Thanks Bart I'll take a look and see if that was the problem, the team did do some changes so binary objects. My worry is that it should not be possible to break the DXA so easily, this simple mistake wasted a great deal of time. Would you recommend that we remove this schema after completing DXA installs?

Comment: That choice is up to you, either remove it, hide it through user rights or map a model for it. The latter two options would be something that I prefer.

Comment: Could we make this change in the DXA cms-import rights-permissions script along with all the others?